# How to get only multiple counts in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im trying to get multiple count values only from multiple documents in a collection which looks like this,( basically I want to get a count of how many are from the 4 directions)

```
{
    "empno": 1500,
    "province": "North"
}
{
    "empno": 1600,
    "province": "West"
}
```

early I found a solution and implemented following query;

```
([
  { "$facet": {
     "N": [
    { "$match": { "province": "North" }},
    { "$count": "N" }
    ],
    "E": [
    { "$match": { "province": "East" }},
    { "$count": "E" }
    ],
    "S": [
    { "$match": { "province": "South" }},
    { "$count": "S" }
    ],
    "W": [
    { "$match": { "province": "West" }},
    { "$count": "W" }
    ]
  }},
    { "$project": {
    "N": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$N.N", 0] },
    "E": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$E.E", 0] },
    "S": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$S.S", 0] },
    "W": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$W.W", 0] },
  }}
  ])
```

The output I get is

```
{ N: 1, W: 1 }
```

How can I get the values only like without the keys and also I want the blank fields that are empty to be with a 0. Like this;

```
 {1, 0, 0, 1}
```

Comment: if you can send some sample documents, and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Facet**

Query

- group by null, is the thing that you needed to add to get the count

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_VVvzjL0O0t)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "g0": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "province": {
              "$eq": "North"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "g1": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "province": {
              "$eq": "East"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "g2": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "province": {
              "$eq": "South"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "g3": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "province": {
              "$eq": "West"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "data": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
          },
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$d.v",
                  []
                ]
              },
              0,
              {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": {
                    "m": {
                      "$arrayElemAt": [
                        "$$d.v",
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "in": "$$m.count"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "as": "d"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": 1
    }
  }
])
```

**Group**

Query

- group is used instead of facet (facet is like 1 aggregation per field)
- each group have its index (from the array), some indexes will be missing (because no documents exist)
- add a zero-data field that has all indexes and count=0 (see bellow)
- add to zero-data, the data found (the ones that existed in the collection,and we have groups for them) the rest keep the count=0

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PKo5UI0-QOy)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$switch": {
          "branches": [
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$province",
                  "North"
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "index": 0,
                "province": "North"
              }
            },
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$province",
                  "East"
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "index": 1,
                "province": "East"
              }
            },
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$province",
                  "South"
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "index": 2,
                "province": "South"
              }
            },
            {
              "case": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$province",
                  "West"
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "index": 3,
                "province": "West"
              }
            }
          ],
          "default": {
            "index": 5
          }
        }
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "data": {
        "$push": {
          "index": "$_id.index",
          "province": "$province",
          "count": "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "zero-data": [
        {
          "index": 0,
          "count": 0
        },
        {
          "index": 1,
          "count": 0
        },
        {
          "index": 2,
          "count": 0
        },
        {
          "index": 3,
          "count": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "data": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$zero-data",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "all_data": "$$value",
                "d": "$$this"
              },
              "in": {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": {
                    "found_data": {
                      "$filter": {
                        "input": "$data",
                        "cond": {
                          "$eq": [
                            "$$d.index",
                            "$$d1.index"
                          ]
                        },
                        "as": "d1"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "in": {
                    "$concatArrays": [
                      "$$all_data",
                      [
                        {
                          "$cond": [
                            {
                              "$eq": [
                                "$$found_data",
                                []
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "index": "$$d.index",
                              "count": 0
                            },
                            {
                              "$arrayElemAt": [
                                "$$found_data",
                                0
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$data",
          "in": "$$this.count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: wow thank you sooo soo much for help!!!. Thats the longest query I've ever seen on mongodb . As a beginner this is the best experience I've had so far ❤

Comment: i added 2 solutions, facet is smaller, facet does 1 aggregation/field, but if you have index on the field will be fast, i mostly did the group because i was curious